# How to check if a JSON object value has changed when new request is captured

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery, local-storage

I have a php script that gets the latest tweet of particular users in JSON format. The JSON is parsed into an AJAX function that displays the latest tweet in an ID on the page. A timer is set for every x seconds to execute the above, retrieving the latest tweet without the user having to refresh the page. This works perfectly.

I am now trying to create a notification feature that displays a notification when there is a new tweet to display. Each tweet has a unique ID called 'id_string' in the JSON retrieved. What I want to do is somehow store the generated id_string's value, and then each time a request is made to retrieve a new tweet, check the new 'id_string' against the stored one, and if it is different then display the notification.

Any ideas on how to go about this would be great?! I've looked into local storage but I'm not very familiar with this, and as far as I'm aware you can't check strings against other strings in local storage.

Here is the necessary code to help with interpreting my question:

PHP to make request to twitter and generate output in JSON format (tweets.php):

```
require_once('config/FrameFunctions.php');

$output = array();

foreach ($tweeters as $i => $tweeter){
    $theTweeter = new Tweeter($tweeter, $tmhOAuth);
    $allinfo = $theTweeter->getTweets();
    $output[$i] = $allinfo;
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($output);
```

The javascript to make the request every x seconds and generate the client output:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.fancybox').fancybox();
   /*
   *  call ajax function and update latest
   */        

    var refreshTweets = function() {
      console.log("updating..");
      $.ajax({url:"tweets.php",success:function(result){
        tweets = eval(result);

        for(i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){
            $("#latesttweet"+(i+1)).html(
               tweets[i][0].user.name + ": " + tweets[i][0].text
             );  
        }

      }});

    }
    refreshTweets();

    //set the time in milliseconds here for each refresh
    setInterval(refreshTweets , 30000); //Interval

});
```

Comment: why do you need local storage to do that? You can store the latest tweet_id in a javascript variable and check it against the new one each time. You could also use a javascript array to keep a log of all the twet ids and compare the new one to it.

Comment: "*as far as I'm aware you can't check strings against other strings in local storage*" - Why not? It would work well. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @JaspalSingh: To make the script still work when the page is refreshed manually, for example - it would be a nice feature

Comment: @tom: Do not use `eval`!!! If you would need to, use `JSON.parse`, but actually jQuery does that already for you. Just set `tweets = result`.

Comment: @Bergi if the page refreshes, you can create the entire data again from server side. His site will unnecessarily be using the client resources when it can perform without it just as well.

Comment: @JaspalSingh: Without local storage, you do not know which tweets the user already got notified of. The server hardly knows that.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the advice, I'll change eval. I'm not sure how I would go about using localStorage to accomplish this task! A code example would be great?

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution based on my comments above

```
/*
NOTE : allTweets will have to be populated with all the tweets ids on the page prior           
to being called in refreshTweets so that it does not trigger fake notifications
*/

    var allTweets = Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        /*
         *  call ajax function and update latest
         */        

        var refreshTweets = function() {
            console.log("updating..");
            $.ajax({url:"tweets.php",success:function(result){
                    tweets = result;

                    for(i=0;i<tweets.length;i++) {

                        //check if its a new tweet or not
                        if (allTweets[tweets[i][0].id_string] === undefined) {
                            allTweets[tweets[i][0].id_string] = 1;    
                            //trigger notification here!
                        }

                        $("#latesttweet"+(i+1)).html(
                        tweets[i][0].user.name + ": " + tweets[i][0].text

                    );  
                    }

                }});

        }
        refreshTweets();

        //set the time in milliseconds here for each refresh
        setInterval(refreshTweets , 30000); //Interval

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll give it a go now and get back to you. As for the note above, I'm not sure how I will achieve this. - The php in my question is where the JSON is retrieved that includes all the tweets, tweet_ids etc. It is only until the 'refreshTweets' function that object values in the JSON are outputted. So how would I go about doing the note you have included above? The 'tweets = result' and for loop is where the values for each twitter user are pulled out, so wouldn't this need to be included earlier in the script?

Comment: Also wouldn't allTweets need a timer to refresh the tweet_id's in the array. Otherwise it would only get the tweet_id's the first time the user loads the page. E.g say there's been 5 new tweets since the first page load, this script would work for the first new tweet, but then any tweets after that the script will still be comparing the latest tweet_id's to the first tweet, not the tweet_id's of the previous tweet. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @Tom: No, `allTweets` stores the ids of all ever shown tweets, not only the latest one.

Comment: @Bergi How would that work then? Because surely it would always be a match because the id will be put into the array before the refresh is made. Could you give me a simple example so I understand your answer more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment inline with the others, but I guess I'm too new.

Anyways, if your not storing sensitive information you can store your data in JSON which can be quickly written to and read by PHP for smaller files. If you're storing a lot of data, you might want to look at saving values to a MySQL database or something similar.

Setting up both JSON storage and MySQL databases seem to be really well documented here.